# Scrolling horizantal on UITableView is changing the position of the UIPageControl which is attached to a scrollView inside the TableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a tableView with dynamically generated custom cells and one of the custom cell contains a scrollView that can scroll vertically and a page control is attached to it.

The user interface structure of the tableview can be seen in the photo.

[image]

I am refreshing the position of the page control in the scrollViewDidScroll method as follows.

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPathPageControl=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.sonDakikaTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathPageControl];


    CGFloat xOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat frameWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;



    int page = floor((xOffset - frameWidth / 2) / frameWidth) + 1;

    UIPageControl *pageControl = (UIPageControl *)[cell.contentView  viewWithTag:14];
    pageControl.currentPage = page; // assigning to pagecontroll


}
```

It is working very fine when the user is scrolling vertical in the scrollView.

However when the user scrolls down on the tableView and the cell with vertical scrollView is not visible anymore, the integer page variable is being updated with 0 and when the user scrolls up and table view cell is visible again, the location of page control is being reset.

I will appreciate if someone can give me an idea about how to prevent this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i added this code

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
  {
  if (_scrollView == self.tableView) return;
  and in your case
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
  {
  if (_scrollView == self.sonDakikaTableView) return;